# How to approximate a non-increasing function from above/below with decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Say I have a non-increasing (not necessarily continuous) function

$$\psi: [1,\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$$

which approaches $0$. Let $0<c<1<C$.  It's my feeling that there should be $C^1$, *strictly decreasing* functions $\overline\psi, \underline\psi$ with

$$c\psi\leq \underline\psi \leq \psi \leq \overline\psi \leq C\psi$$

It seems like you could maybe prove this by piecing together some $C^1$ functions defined on closed intervals. But I wonder if there's a cleaner, possibly fancier way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any continuous functions $\underline{\psi}$ and $\overline{\psi}$ satisfying your inequalities.  If $\psi$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=a$ with
$\lim_{x \to a-} \psi(x) = B$ and $\lim_{x \to a+} \psi(x) = b$, then we must have

$$ c B \le \underline{\psi}(a) \le \overline{\psi}(a) \le C b$$

which is a contradiction if $B/b > C/c$.  So this is not always possible.
In fact, it's not hard to construct non-increasing functions with infinitely many jumps such that your inequalities don't work for any $0 < c <C$.

Comment: Ah, good point. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks: I edited it.

Comment: Surely discontinuity is the only obstruction, though, wouldn't you think?

Comment: Yes, I would think so.